# Resizing and centering an image using CSS

Tags: html, css

My scenario:

- I have an image of size 1900 x 1600 pixels.
- I have a `div` of size 200 x 150 pixels.

I have resized the image using the following CSS:

```
max-width:300px;
max-height:300px;
```

The height will be kept in proportion, so in this example it will be 252 px.

How can I center the image in the `div`? I mean something like:

```
background-position: center center;
```

Is this sort of thing possible with CSS 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean

```
background:url("test.png");
background-size: 300px auto;
background-position: center center;
```

?

Answer (score 0):

To center the DIV within an element, you would set a `width` and `margin` with the left and right margins set to auto:

`div {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 300px;
}`